# Github actions build UWP project

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, github-actions

I am not able to build a UWP project with Github actions. I run `dotnet build --configuration Release` on the whole solution, but for UWP the error is:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dncs\3.1.101\x64\sdk\3.1.101\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v16.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dncs\3.1.101\x64\sdk\3.1.101\\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v16.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Locally I use VS 2019 Pro, 16.4.5. I have this import in my csproj (generated by default VS template):

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" />
```

I tried installing the `visualstudio2019-workload-universal` with chocolatey, but same result.

Links to [Build](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet/runs/451316572?check_suite_focus=true), [yaml](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet/blob/feature/v4/.github/workflows/dotnetcore.yml), [csproj](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet/blob/feature/v4/samples/UWP/Auth.UWP.Sample.csproj)

Any idea how to fix the build issue?

Comment: Knowing very little about GitHub actions, I'd guess you'll have more luck calling msbuild on the project. The dotnet.exe build is sufficiently different (targeted at .NET Core) than UWP (which runs .NET Native).